# Inline if condition inside image src

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4 where I have an image, which render's the image dynamically like:

```
<img id="imgThumbnail" src="@Url.Content(@ControlUtilities.FormatUrl(" ~/GetImage?imageid=" + @Model.ImageID))" />
```

Now, I want to check, if `@ControlUtilities.FormatUrl("~/GetImage?imageid="+ @Model.ImageID)` return's null or blank then replace it with `'/img/noimage.gif'`

Something like:

```
src= "@Url.Content(@ControlUtilities.FormatUrl("~/GetImage?imageid=" + @Model.ImageID)) || '/img/noimage.gif'"
```

Is it possible to do it inline in HTML itself? Or I have to handle it thru jQuery?

Why I want to do this is, when ever the API `GetImage` return's blank/null, the output is an empty image tag or to be precise broken image is getting displayed. Alternatives would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do it inline in HTML itself?

Yep, you can definitely do a `null` check inline

```
src="@(Url.Content(ControlUtilities.FormatUrl("~/GetImage?" + Model.ImageID) ?? "/img/noimage.gif"))
```

If you need to check for it being blank as well then it would just start to become unreadable so I would suggest you moved it into a variable

```
@{
    var imageUrl = ControlUtilities.FormatUrl("~/GetImage?" + Model.ImageID);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl)) {
        imageUrl = "/img/noimage.gif";
    }
}
...
<image id="imgThumbnail" src="@Url.Content(imageUrl)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<img id="imgThumbnail" src= "@Url.Content(@ControlUtilities.FormatUrl(("~/GetImage?imageid=" 
+ @Model.ImageID)??"/img/noimage.gif"))"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    string src;
}
<img id="imgThumbnail" src="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(src = Url.Content(@ControlUtilities.FormatUrl("~/GetImage?imageid=" + Model.ImageID))) ? "'/img/noimage.gif'" : src)" />
```

If u will just use '??' operator, the blank 'src' could be placed in img tag